# Referencing argument in with statement

Tags: actionscript-3

Is there a way to reference the argument in a with statement? It's like when you have class variables and a constructor and you do this

```
var blah;
public function foo(blah) {
    this.blah = blah;
}
```

Is there a way to do the same like

```
public function foo(blah) {
    with(cat){
        bar += blah;
    }
}
```

I want to add cat.bar by the blah given to the function.

It's easy to just rename the argument, but I'm curious if there's a way to do it. Thanks

Comment: Should work fine if it's within scope (defined within the class, outside of methods).

Comment: really? when I tried it didn't work as expected. nearly thought flash couldn't do math properly :/

Comment: That's one reason why `with` is evil. It's recommend not to use it.

Comment: Am I the only one confused as to where `cat` came from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's what the `with` is for

tried this in wonder.fl and it works fine. Can you specify what you were expecting to see vs what it did?

```
package {
    import flash.text.TextField;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    public class FlashTest extends Sprite {

        public var myMC:Sprite = new Sprite();    
        public var tf:TextField = new TextField();    

        public function FlashTest() {

            addChild(tf);

            fooWith(20);

        }

        public function fooWith($x:Number):void{

            with(myMC){
                x+=$x;
            }

            tf.text =  "' "  + myMC.x + " '";
        }

    }
}
```